# Why [ProductCode] can be expaneded while [ProductName] can not?

Tags: wix

I have WiX code like this:

```
<DirectoryRef Id="MyShortcutsDir">
    <Component Id="CMP_StartMenuShortcuts" Guid="62A9F5D2-F9D9-4F9B-8382-D470E11B2332">
        <Shortcut Id="docEng" Name="UFCOM user guide - ENG (pdf)" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]UFCOM user guide - ENG.pdf" />
        <Shortcut Id="docChs" Name="UFCOM user guide - CHS (pdf)" Target="[INSTALLFOLDER]UFCOM user guide - CHS.pdf" />
        <Shortcut Id="UninstallShortcut" Name="Uninstall [ProductName] ~ [ProductVersion]" Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe" Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" Description="Remove UFCOM from your Windows" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveMyShortcutsDir" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\Newland Auto-ID\UFCOM" Name="installed" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes" />
        <!-- On Win7, these shortcuts(.lnk) resides in "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\UFCOM" -->
    </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

But I find that [ProductCode] can be expaneded while [ProductName] can not, why is it so? Then how to reference product name define in  element?

```
<Product Id="*" Name="UFCOM Driver 1.3.6" ... >
</Product>
```

[image: Code screen shot]
[image: ProductName is not expanded, damn]

Comment: Unclear what you want to ask. Can't find what you want to express with `expaneded`. Why do you expect something different than the string you wrote in your XML file `Uninstall [ProductName]`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Property names in square brackets are only expanded by the MSI installer for data in [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx) column types in the MSI database.  The expansion happens when the product is installed.

In the [Shortcut](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371847(v=vs.85).aspx) table in the MSI database:

- The *Arguments* column is type [Formatted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368609(v=vs.85).aspx), so `[ProductCode]` will be expanded when the product is installed.
- The *Name* column is type [Filename](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368590(v=vs.85).aspx), so `[ProductName]` and `[ProductVersion]` will not be expanded when the product is installed.

You could use WIX properties, which are expanded during the WIX build process.  For example:

```
<?define ProductName='My Product Name' ?>
<?define ProductVersion='X.Y.Z' ?>

<Shortcut Id="UninstallShortcut" 
     Name="Uninstall $(var.ProductName) ~ $(var.ProductVersion)" 
     Target="[System64Folder]msiexec.exe" 
     Arguments="/x [ProductCode]" 
     Description="Remove UFCOM from your Windows" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Properties in brackets are expanded in "formatted" attributes.  For shortcuts, [Shortcut table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa371847.aspx) defines that Arguments is formatted but the Name is not.

You may define a variable

```
  <?define MyProductName = "UFCOM Driver 1.3.6" ?>
```

and then use it in both Product/@Name and Shortcut/@Name:

```
<Product Name="$(var.MyProductName)"

<Shortcut Name="Uninstall $(var.MyProductName)"
```